# Как определить было ли нажатие на рекламу Adsense на сайте?

Tags: javascript

Есть ли какие то методы определения, была ли нажата реклама на сайте? При нажатии на рекламу открывается новое окно сайта с рекламой, можно ли хотя бы как то вычислить адрес выхода? на чей именно сайт пользователь перешел

Comment: Adsense на сайте внедряется через iframe, если получится повесить на iframe addEventListener, то Вы сможете отследить факт клика по рекламе. Адрес перехода узнать не сможете из-за политики безопасности в браузере.

Answer (score 1):

адрес перехода вы не сможете узнать потому, что сначала произойдет переход на зашифрованный одноразовый url рекламной сети, а оттуда редирект на сайт рекламодателя. Второй раз редирект сработать не должен.

1) потому, что рекламная сеть не хочет, чтобы вы знали, кому льется трафик с вашего сайта, потому, что тогда вы можете напрямую пойти к реклу и сказать ему - рекл, рекламируйся у нас по особым условиям. Т.е. вы используете технологии и мощности рекламной сети для того, чтобы за их счет найти себе выгодного рекла.

2) если вы знаете, кто куда кликал, вы нарушаете прайваси пользователя, может у вас на сайте обязательная регистрация, но при этом крутится реклама фирмы адвокатов по разводам. или там, условно, лекарства от сифилиса.

3) как правильно указали в комментариях, браузер вам не даст, ибо безопасность.